# Prove that the quadrilateral whose vertices are the midpoints of the sides of an arbitrary quadrilateral is a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

> Prove that the quadrilateral PQRS, whose vertices are the midpoints of the sides of an arbitrary quadrilateral ABCD, is a parallelogram. This is an exercise in a linear algebra textbook so I would like to solve it using vectors.

I tried expressing the sides of the parallelogram in terms of the half-sizes of $ABCD$ eg. $PQ = PB + BQ$ but I that probably isn't enough information because the resulting equations did not lead anywhere useful. (Relevant figure can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQK8v.png)).

Comment: Note that this result is known as Varignon's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varignon%27s_theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The midpoint of $AB$ is $\frac12(A+B)$.

The midpoint of $BC$ is $\frac12(B+C)$.

The vector from the midpoint of $AB$ to the midpoint of $BC$ is $\frac12(B+C)-\frac12(A+B) = \frac12(C-A)$.

Repeat for $AD$ and $DC$ to see that you get the same vector there.